# I am not be able to record my voice MY app is that I auto attend the call and then record it and save it

Tags: android

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I am using this code but did not understand how to convert mp3 file and saves it in phone storage

Comment: try to reorganize your header to make it shorter. You can put the rest of your question inside description. Also, it is not clear, what you are trying to do...

Comment: i want to record call and stores it in phone storage

Comment: plz help me in this matter

Comment: just use search - there ara a lot of similar question here.